# Split specific string from lines via regex

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I have been trying to extract certain equal to `40` values get the sixth last word from multiple lines inside a .txt file with PowerShell.

I have code so far :

```
$file = Get-Content 'c:\temp\file.txt'
$Array = @()
foreach ($line in $file)
{
$Array += $line.split(",")[6]
}
$Array
$Array | sc "c:\temp\export2.txt"
```

Txt file : (may be duplicate lines such as hostname01)

```
4626898,0,3,0,POL,INCR,hostname01,xx,1549429809,0000000507,1549430316,xxx,0,40,1,xxxx,51870834,5040,100
4626898,0,3,0,POL,INCR,hostname02,xx,1549429809,0000000507,1549430316,xxx,0,15,1,xxxx,51870834,5040,100
4626898,0,3,0,POL,INCR,hostname03 developer host,xx,1549429809,0000000507,1549430316,xxx,0,40,1,xxxx,51870834,5040,100
4626898,0,3,0,POL,INCR,hostname01,xx,1549429809,0000000507,1549430316,xxx,0,40,1,xxxx,51870834,5040,100
```

This is what I want :

```
hostname01
hostname02
hostname03 developer host
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a *fast* solution, but a *convenient and flexible* one:

- Since your text file is effectively a CSV file, you can use `Import-Csv`.

  - Since your data is missing is a *header row* (column names), which we can supply to `Import-Csv` via its `-Header` parameter.
  - Since you're interested in columns number `7` (hostnames) and `14` (the number whose value should be `40`), we need to supply column names (of our choice) for columns 1 through 14.
- `Import-Csv` conveniently converts the CSV rows to (custom) *objects*, whose properties you can query with `Where-Object` and selectively extract with `Select-Object`; adding `-Unique` suppresses duplicate values.

To put it all together:

```
Import-Csv c:\temp\file.txt -Header (1..14) | 
  Where-Object 14 -eq 40 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 7 -Unique
```

<sup>For convenience we've named the columns `1`, `2`, ... using a range expression (`1..14`), but you're free to use descriptive names.</sup>

Assuming that `c:\temp\file.txt` contains your sample data, the above yields:

```
hostname01
hostname03 developer host
```

To output to a file, pipe the above to `Set-Content`, as in your question:

```
... | Set-Content c:\temp\export2.txt
```

Comment: There is a speed related follow-up question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213171/extracting-string-via-powershell) with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a non-capturing group to look through the string for the correct format and reference the name of your 6 element with the 1st capture group `$1`:

```
(?:\d+,\d,\d,\d,[A-Z]+,[A-Z]+,)([a-zA-Z 0-9]+)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LTnwCX/1)

- `(?: )` - Specifies a non-capture group (meaning it's not referenced via $1, or $2 like you normally would with a capture group
- `\d+,` (I won't repeat all of these, but) looking for a one or more digits followed by a literal `,`.
- `[A-Z]+,` - Finds an all capital letter string, followed by a literal `,` (this occurs twice).
- ([a-zA-Z 0-9]+) - The capture group you're looking for, $1, that will capture all characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, spaces, and digits up until a character not in this set (in this case, a comma). Giving you the text you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the desired field is always the 6th in the line it is easier to split each line and fetch the 6th member:

```
Get-Content 'c:\temp\file.txt' | Foreach-Object {($_ -split ',')[6]} | Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: But I will to extract certain equal to 40 values get the sixth last word.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: I mean , I just want to capture line which is belong `40` value within   such 
 as 4626898,0,3,0,POL,INCR,hostname01,xx,1549429809,0000000507,1549430316,xxx,0,`40`,1,xxxx,51870834,5040,100
 .

Answer (score 0):

Below should work with what you are trying to do

```
Get-Content 'c:\temp\file.txt' | %{ 
    $_.Split(',')[6]
}| select -Unique
```